# Test for expected timeout in mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a Faye publish/subscribe server that sends a message to new subscribers only if a message has already been sent to the other subscribers.  I am using mocha for unit testing.

This test works to confirm the basic functionality:

```
    it('should send a special message to new subscribers', function(done){
        testerPubSub.setLastJsonContent('some arbitrary content');
        var subscription = client.subscribe("/info", function(message) {
            assert.equal(true, message.text.indexOf('some arbitrary content') !== -1, 'new subscriber message not sent');
            done();
        });
        subscription.cancel();
    });
```

But I would now like to test the case where there has not been a message sent to previous subscribers.  This test would be something like:

```
    it('should not send a special message to new subscribers if no data has been retrieved', function(done){
        testerPubSub.setLastJsonContent(null);
        var messageReceived = false;
        var subscription = client.subscribe("/sales", function(message) {
            messageReceived = true;
        });

        ////need to magically wait 2 seconds here for the subscription callback to timeout

        assert.equal(false, messageRecieved, 'new subscriber message received');
        subscription.cancel;
        done();
    });
```

Of course, the magic sleep function is problematic.  Is there a better way to be doing this sort of "I expect the callback to never get fired" test?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I thought of one possible solution, but it is a bit too dependent on timing for me to think of it as THE solution:

```
    it('should not send a special message to new subscribers if no data has been retrieved', function(done){
        testerPubSub.setLastJsonContent(null);
        var messageReceived = false;
        var subscription = client.subscribe("/sales", function(message) {
            assert.fail(message.text, '', 'Should not get message', '=');
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            done();
        }, 1500);

        subscription.cancel;
    });
```

This test passes, but the 1500ms pause just seems rather arbitrary.  I'm really saying "right before I think it's going to timeout, jump in and say it's OK.